# Why is there an error running the command "npm run tauri"？

Tags: tauri

C:\WINDOWS\System32\tauri-app>npm run tauri

> tauri-app@0.0.0 tauri
> tauri dev

[tauri:dev] Running `yarn dev`
yarn run v1.22.17
$ vite
Pre-bundling dependencies:
vue
(this will be run only when your dependencies or config have changed)

vite v2.8.6 dev server running at:

> Local: http://localhost:3000/
> Network: use `--host` to expose

ready in 523ms.

```
Updating crates.io index
```

warning: spurious network error (2 tries remaining): failed to send request: 操作超时
; class=Os (2)
warning: spurious network error (1 tries remaining): failed to send request: 操作超时
; class=Os (2)
error: failed to get `serde` as a dependency of package `app v0.1.0 (C:\WINDOWS\System32\tauri-app\src-tauri)`

Caused by:
failed to load source for dependency `serde`

Caused by:
Unable to update registry `crates-io`

Caused by:
failed to fetch `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`

Caused by:
failed to send request: 操作超时
; class=Os (2)

Answer (score 1):

Network request failed when install rust dependency because of Chinese FireWall.

You can use proxy or [config cargo mirror in China](https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/help/crates.io-index.git/).